# Different websites on "example.com" and "www.example.com"

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain

I have an `A` record for my domain for `example.com` that points to my server's IP address.
I would like to modify my DNS records so that `www.example.com` points to another server.

Is this possible, and would I do that by simply creation a new `A` type record?
Wouldn't `example.com` override my `www.example.com` record?

Comment: From your comments on the answers, it sounds to me like what you really want to do is to run virtual hosts on the same server. Its not necessary to run separate servers. Your A records (or CNAME records) might end up both pointing to the same machine.

Comment: Out of interest why would you want to do this from a Users point of view this would be really confusing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is you would make an A record named `@` that  points to the IP where `example.com` sits and an A record named `www` that points to the IP where `www.example.com` sits.

Some DNS services (such as Amazon's route53) use a blank A record, rather than naming it `@`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the technical details, I wanted to make sure that this was the proper way to execute what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, `www` is a subdomain of `example.com`. As with any subdomain, you can create a `CNAME` record to point it to another host. See this for more on CNAME's and an example of pointing `www` to another host:  [DNS Made Easy: Example 3](http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/record-entry/cname/)

I'd strongly recommend against doing this however if it will take them to another site because it will really confuse visitors since most sites redirect `www.example.com` to `example.com` or vice versa, and they might type either into a browser's address bar.

Neither one overrides the other, unless setup in your server to do so through a redirect (i.e., a 301 redirect).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, my client actually needs to have it set up that way because one site will be used only for mobile devices (the actual app) and the other for non-mobile devices (the corporate website).

Comment: No problem. I think the standard for mobile content is `m.example.com`, which is a CNAME record as well.